# Can Windows 2008 64bit make use of a 6 core cpu?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, multi-core

There's a version of AMD Phenom CPU which is 6 cores. Would Windows 2008 64 bit & SQL Server 2008 64 bit make use of all the cores? Any special settings of the OS or sql server needed to benefit from all the 6 cores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use all cores the limitations are on sockets.  Standard can only go up to 4 sockets.  Here is the [edition comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-specs.aspx) chart.

Here is the [comparison chart](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx) for SQL server